# How to enable NFS v2 in WSL2?

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nfs, wsl2

It only has v3 and v4, but my client (U-Boot) only supports v2

```sh
$ rpcinfo -p localhost | grep nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
```

I tried changing `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` according to Google like:

```
RPCNFSDCOUNT="--nfs-version 2 8"
```

or

```
RPCNFSDCOUNT="--no-nfs-version 4"
```

They did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have no direct experience with this myself, but according to [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1193577/1165986) it should be:

```
RPCNFSDOPTS="--nfs-version 2,3,4"
```

Comment: Not work as my question said.

Comment: @JksLiu The lines that you have in your question are very different ...

Comment: Thanks for your explain. I tried many options including yours in the config file, but none of them worked.